# Make Realm work with SwiftUI List(children:)

Tags: swiftui, realm

I am trying to use Realm as a database with a parent/children relationship and show the data in a hierarchical [SwiftUI List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) using the `children:` initializer. I oriented myself at the [SwiftUI+Realm tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/). My Realm class looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
    
class BlockList: RealmSwift.Object, RealmSwift.ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: RealmSwift.ObjectId
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var childBlockLists = RealmSwift.List<BlockList>()
    @Persisted(originProperty: "childBlockLists") var parentBlockList: RealmSwift.LinkingObjects<BlockList>
    
    convenience init(title: String) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
   }
}
```

Then my content view looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(BlockList.self) var blockLists
    
    var body: some View {
        let parentBlockLists = blockLists.where {
            ($0.parentBlockList.count == 0)
        }
        
        List(parentBlockLists) { blockList in
            Text(blockList.title)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let newBlockList = BlockList(title: "New List")
        let newSubBlockList = BlockList(title: "New SubList")
        newBlockList.childBlockLists.append(newSubBlockList)
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newBlockList)
        }
    }
}
```

This shows all lists that do not have a parent. The next step would be to use `List(children:)` to show the data hierarchically, ie show those lists that have sublists with a chevron to expand the list.

For this purpose, the children parameter expects the key paths to the child nodes. However, I cannot figure out how to provide that. I tried to write an extension to BlockList and provide a function that casts the children into something useful, but none of my approaches work:

```
extension BlockList {
    var childBlockListsArray: AnyRealmCollection<BlockList> {
        AnyRealmCollection(childBlockLists)
//        guard let set = childBlockLists as? Array<BlockList>, set.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
//        childBlockLists.count == 0 ? nil : AnyRealmCollection(childBlockLists)
//        childBlockLists.count == 0 ? nil : Array(childBlockLists)
    }
}
```

I feel I get closest with casting in `AnyRealmCollection` and then use

```
List(AnyRealmCollection(parentBlockLists), children: \.childBlockListsArray)
```

But I still get the error

> Key path value type 'AnyRealmCollection' cannot be
> converted to contextual type 'AnyRealmCollection?'

How can I provide the correct `Realm` data and their children key paths to be shown in SwiftUIs `List`?

Comment: The issue you're having is not clear. You've got all of the parents, right? `parentBlockLists` so within each of those you have each parents child list `@Persisted var childBlockLists` so... If you want to list parents and then their children, it seems you have everything you need? Perhaps re-thinking the model may add clarity. A `Person` object that has a `childList` of other `Person` objects may be a bit simpler.

Comment: Review my answer - let me know if I misunderstood the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try an answer as I think that everything you need already exists in your question without any additional code.

I believe the goal is to generate a list of parents, and then a chevron or disclosure triangles in the UI for the user to click on to then show their children - all done with one model.

Here's your (simplified) model

```
class BlockList: RealmSwift.Object {
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var childBlockLists = RealmSwift.List<BlockList>()
    @Persisted(originProperty: "childBlockLists") var parentBlockList: RealmSwift.LinkingObjects<BlockList>

    convenience init(title: String) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
   }
}
```

Now populate realm with some data to test with; parents and children. In this case ParentA has two children while ParentB and ParentC have one.

```
let parentA = BlockList(title: "parent A")
let parentB = BlockList(title: "parent B")
let parentC = BlockList(title: "parent C")

let child0ofParentA = BlockList(title: "child 0 of Parent A")
let child1ofParentA = BlockList(title: "child 1 of Parent A")

let child0ofParentB = BlockList(title: "child 0 of Parent B")

let child0ofParentC = BlockList(title: "child 0 of Parent C")

parentA.childBlockLists.append(child0ofParentA)
parentA.childBlockLists.append(child1ofParentA)

parentB.childBlockLists.append(child0ofParentB)

parentC.childBlockLists.append(child0ofParentC)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add([parentA, parentB, parentC])
}
```

Then finally, let's read that data in and present a list - similar to what you'd do in the UI

```
//get all of the parents
let parents = realm.objects(BlockList.self).where { $0.childBlockLists.count > 0 }

parents.forEach { parent in
    print("parent title: \(parent.title)")

    parent.childBlockLists.forEach { child in
        print("   child title: \(child.title)")
    }
}
```

and the output - which would be the same as a user taps a discosure triangle for each parent

```
parent title: parent A
   child title: child 0 of Parent A
   child title: child 1 of Parent A
parent title: parent B
   child title: child 0 of Parent B
parent title: parent C
   child title: child 0 of Parent C
```

Note that I am not using `parentBlockList` at all so it could be removed in this use case. Perhaps you want a want to transverse the graph back to the parent from the child? If so, leave it in.

The SwiftUI part is just displaying a child objects just like the parent objects are displayed and you seems to know how to display a list of objects already.

Comment: Great example, and yes I see what you mean when you say OP already has everything he needs. This could/should be the accepted solution @OP. However the problem is that this won’t work with `SwiftUI.List` - which is really a limitation of that view. So I guess the real answer to OP’s question is: don’t use `List`, just use two nested `ForEach` views (SwiftUI ‘s version of `.forEach(_:)`) to display the rows. But you will lose all `List` functionality, that’s the downside to this solution.

Comment: @Jay @Cheezzhead: Thanks both of you for your efforts! I want to accomplish something like this Xcodes project navigator view, in which you can nest folders and files up to an arbitrary level. In my case though, I have only one type: `BlockLists`. So yes, I want to achieve a chevron to show/hide the children. I also want to be able to drag/drop them to rearrange and that kind of stuff. I am no professional programmer and this is a personal project of min. I lack the deep knowledge you both obviously have. The design might need to a rethink, but I wouldn't even know how.

Answer (score 1):

Just use arrays.

```
extension BlockList {
    // Map the children to an array. 
    // Note: SwiftUI.List expects this variable to be optional
    var children: [BlockList]? { self.childBlockLists.map { $0 } }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(BlockList.self) var blockLists
    
    // Perform your filtering in a computed variable. Avoid performing calculations in the view's body
    var parentBlockLists: [BlockList] {
        blockLists
            .where { $0.parentBlockList.count == 0 } // Filter results
            .map { $0 } // Map to array
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(parentBlockLists, children: \.children) { blockList in
            Text(blockList.title)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DaPhil While this solution may work, it's generally not a good idea to cast Realm Collections to arrays unless you are certain you know that size of that array and it will not overload memory. e.g. Realm Objects are lazily loaded - meaning that have very little memory impact. Casting them to an array loads ALL of the data which can overwhelm the device as your dataset grows. For example suppose you started including an image with every BlockList - that's going to crash your app quickly when casting that data to an Array. Realm has this functionality built in so that's a better bet.

Comment: Well, the `Results` or `List` object is also loaded in memory. They are loaded lazily, but so is `.map`. Also images are not persistable in Realm. So I don't see the difference really? You're right to some extent, of course, that mapping to an array loses some of the functionality (so one should be considerate of the memory implications), but the fact of the matter is that Swift is a strongly-typed language and `List` and `Results` are two different types. Using them in conjunction will always lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not really accurate. `Result` and `List` are not loaded into memory - they are [lazily loaded](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/read/?_ga=2.56705772.758228516.1668088609-762773769.1656853287#results-are-lazy). Images are 100% persistable in Realm - here's an entire project that does just that. [O-FISH](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-cloud-rescue-protecting-oceans-opensource-application) and [O-FISH](https://wildaid.github.io). We have a number of projects that store image thumbnails in Realm. Just trying to prevent future issues.

Comment: Oh - looks like you may not be familiar with Realm *and List and Results are two different types* correct but `List` in realm is actually a `RealmSwift.List` - Realm has it's own [List](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#collections-as-properties) property, unrelated to Swift `List`. Again, the answer is not bad by any means but may lead to future issues unless certain precautions are put into place (limiting image size if used, controlling the number of objects loaded etc)

Comment: Per my earlier comment: _They are loaded lazily, but so is `.map`_. Yes I'm well aware what `RealmSwift.List` is so your comment is a bit superfluous - it doesn't change the fact that `RealmSwift.Results` and `RealmSwift.List` are two different types.

Comment: In regards to images: I should have specified that they are not persistable **by default**. Anything can be persistable by conforming to the `CustomPersistable` protocol, so yes images too.

Comment: List and Results are both [Realm Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#results-and-sectioned-results) - they are very similar in functionality but have two different purposes. No need to be defensive as I wasn't stating the answer was wrong - its important the OP understand the options they have and this option may need additional checks in the future to keep the app from crashing. I am still not sure why the OP needs anything more than what they already have - it seems the overall design may need a re-think. IMO.

Comment: They are both realm collections but they are of a different type. This is the exact problem that OP was facing: `List(_:children:)` expects the keypath to the children objects to be the same type as the data, and in the example the data is a `Results` object while the children are a `List` object. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: And yes, agreed re: the overall design re-think. But I often get that feeling when browsing stackoverflow examples :D

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question but check out my answer. Feel free to correct my thinking if I am off target.

Comment: @Jay @Cheezzhead: I understand that using an array is not ideal because it will load each and every data. Therefore, I should not use arrays and instead use some `RealmCollection` type directly. Would it help to not save big data like images or attachments directly in a `Realm.Object` but only an identifier (ie a `String`) to such an object (which I would implement as an additional `Realm.Object` in my model)? That way, I could prevent loading a lot of big data and may only load when really necessary? Would that help to still use the array approach?